# Increasing offer at the final stage

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

All right, so I am currently employed, and I'm looking for some new opportunities. I found two companies - in one I'm waiting for a decision after 2nd tech interview, in the second I have passed everything and got the "offer-interview" scheduled this week. I'll talk about the second:

During the very first hr talk I made a mistake and told too low salary requirements - let's say 5k$/month. I would want 6k$/month instead. I got to the final stage now, they even called me to confirm the salary, I did. I have a final interview scheduled now, yet I still have to inform them about this salary increase.

The job advertisement for this position has very high salary range - let's say 8k$ - 14k$/month. It's very high for the location, that's why I was aiming lower (which is still pretty high). It's also a big international corporation.

So - how should I approach informing them about my salary requirements increase? Should I call them before the interview, or tell about it face to face? Should I tell them that I have a counter offer, and that's where my increase come from? How does my situation look like?

Comment: You asked for a salary lower than was advertised?

Answer (score 1):

Wait for an offer, but be prepared with your reason to ask for more. It is possible you've learned more about this position during the interview process. When were you given the complete list of benefits? How long have you had to think about the position?

You're always going to justify any increase, so get in the practice of understanding what you're worth.

Comment: Is "I made a mistake and told too low salary requirements" a good reason? Seems kinda lame to me. Or are you saying to make something up?

Comment: @WorkerDrone it's not a good reason, but it's closer to a good reason than one might realize. I tried writing up an answer.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I also agree with WorkerDrone that it's lame. But it is what it is (and most of all, it's the truth spoken from the heart), so he'd retain his dignity and (possibly) get what he wants and *that's* real value.

Comment: @WorkerDrone - Now that I know what is required, I've found there are comparable jobs that offer more money. There must be some reason you decided to ask for more money beyond, "I didn't realize 55K is more than 50K, so I want the bigger number."

Answer (score 1):

The company said they value the work at between $8k and $14k per month. You walked in and said you'd do it for $5k per month. They called you back to confirm, and you did so. Now you want to tell them $6k per month. You have two problems.

1. You are going back on your (confirmed) requested salary. They already know you will do the work for $5k per month, so you have no leverage to request more at this point. Also, it will make them believe - correctly - that you didn't put proper thought into estimating your salary expectations.
2. You asked for much less than the company estimated the position is worth. Don't do this. You are shortchanging yourself and you are sending the message that you are less valuable than other candidates for the same position.

Don't lie about a fictional counteroffer. Just own up and explain that after further reflection on the job requirements, you think $6k per month is a reasonable salary. It's still going to be strange that you're offering to work far below the minimum they offered, but you can't realistically come back and ask for $8k at this point. They might just rubber stamp it ($5k, $6k, what's the difference when you're under the minimum) or they might stand their ground because they know you'll take $5k.

Next time don't low-ball yourself!

Comment: Why is 6k realistic and 8k not realistic?

Comment: I can't speak to what's actually an appropriate salary for the job, but upping your salary requirements by 30% between the first interview and the last is uncommon.